# How can I determine the ng-grid version?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using the minified version of ng-grid (ng-grid.min.js) - how do I determine the version #? In Chrome I type ngGrid in the console, but don't see a way to obtain the version number. The minified JS does not have the version in a obvious location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at full source on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/ng-grid-2.0.7.debug.js)) there is no version anywhere in the file. The only place it can be found is in the file name. In your case its been removed, so you could do a file comparison with past minified versions to come up with an answer.

Comment: It's silly for any Javascript library to not include version number in its source